# JavaFX, avoid connecting two controllers without using static

Tags: java, javafx

I'm developing a project using JavaFX. I made a dashboard using a BorderPane. This BorderPane must have all the buttons on the left, and the central and right panes must dinamically change when i press the button.

I'm also using an MVC pattern. I'll describe what i did until now: i have an HomePage Controller, which stores the BorderPane injected with the @FXML tag. I also have different classes for every GUI (always using the MVC pattern, so for example a CreateUser GUI with its CreateUser controller associated).

The behaviour i want is that when you press a button, that button sets the central pane of the Homepage's Borderpane with the right GUI. I can do that since the button is associated with the controller of the class it should expand upon (in simple terms, if i press the 'Create User' button, its action listener is stored in the CreateUser controller, which calls the 'openCreateUserGUI' method contained in the CreateUserGUI. This method simply loades a node, and returns it, so it can be added to the BorderPane).

My problem is the following: to set the BorderPane with the press of a button, i wanted to make the BorderPane in HomePageController 'static', since in this pattern, you should never connect controllers with each other (or, at least, this is what they taught me at university), and i cannot access the BorderPane if i don't declare an instance of HomePageController in my CreateUserController. So, setting it static seemed like the right approach. But making a @FXML 'static' doesn't work. Furthermore, i found out that making something 'static' is not the right approach when you want to refer to a variable without having an instance of that class.

I read multiple questions here on STO about this topic, but haven't found a solution.

How can I solve this? Should i just connect the two controllers, or is there an alternative to using static?

I'll post some code to have a minimal reproducible example:

```
public class HomepageController {


    @FXML
    BorderPane borderPane;

    @FXML
    Label labelUsername;


    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        labelUsername.setText(Utente.getUsername());
    }

  
    public void setBorderPaneCenter(Node node){
       this.borderPane.getChildren().remove(borderPane.getCenter());
       this.borderPane.setCenter(node);
    }

    public void setBorderPaneRight(Node node){
        this.borderPane.getChildren().remove(borderPane.getRight());
        this.borderPane.setCenter(node);
    }

}
```

In CreateUserController, I have this action event. I'd like something like this, if there's an alternative to using static (since it's not the right approach)

```
public class CreateUserController {

// to avoid using static, i should make this:
HomepageController hmc = new HomepageController();


   public void clickButtonCreateUser(ActionEvent event){
        try {    
     hmc.setBorderPaneRight(createUserGUI.openCreateUserGUI(event));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

It just seems not optimal to me connecting these two controllers. But using static is not the right approach either.

Comment: Connect MVC's via the Controllers.  It's the only way.  What I would do is have the "Main" Controller (associated with the BorderPane), instantiate all of the other MVC's (via their Controllers) and then grab a reference to their Views.  Then pass those Views to the "Main" MVC's View as constructor parameters.  Then the "Main" View can have logic that swaps out the centre of the BorderPane with whichever View is associated with the button that was pressed.

Comment: If you're using MVC, the standard way to do this is for both (or all) controllers to have a reference to a single model instance. Each controller updates and/or observes the model in the usual MVC way. This completely avoids any controllers having to communicate with each other (which is basically the entire point of MVC). Can you post your model class?

Comment: Also, please post a [mre]. The code you posted would, in any reasonable context I can think of, throw a null pointer exception when you call `hmc.setBorderPaneRight(...)` because `borderPane` won't be initialized in an arbitrary instance of `HomepageController` (it will only be initialized in the instance created by an `FXMLLoader`).

Comment: @James_D I don't think this is true about the "basically the entire point of MVC).  The idea behind MVC is to isolate the elements of the View from the business logic.  Sharing a Model between two MVC's creates an incredible amount of coupling.  It's entirely possible that each of his sub-MVC's serves an entirely different purpose, and there's no shared data elements between any of them.  In that case, the only reference between the MVC's would be that the master View knows about the other Views.

Comment: @DaveB The point of MVC is to decouple the view from the *data*. The *only* consistent aspect of the different variants of MVC (MVP, MVVM, etc.) is the existence of a model which is completely agnostic as regards the view. The relationship between view and controller varies depending on the MVC flavor (passive view, supervising controller, etc.). When the user changes what is displayed, they are changing *state* of the application, which should be part of the model (or some aspect of the model). The main view can respond to those changes. The OP needs to post a [mre] to make this concrete.

Comment: @James_D  It absolutely doesn't decouple the View from the data.  In fact the main coupling element is the Presentation Data.  In MVC for example, the Model changes the data and the View changes accordingly.  You cannot change the structure of the Presentation Data without messing with the View as well.  What is decoupled is the business logic, which is in the Model and the Domain Data which is also in the Model.  The Model isn't dependent on how the View uses the Presentation Data, nor is the View dependent on how the Model uses the Presentation data.